# Printing name of a key in SDL

Tags: c++, sdl

My SDL program is returning a memory address which is same for all keys, I'm attempting to print the name of the key, i.e if the user presses 'F' key the console outputs 'F'. How would i go about editing my code to achieve this?

```
void Game::handleEvents()
    {
        SDL_Event event;
        if(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch (event.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    g_bRunning = false;
                    //SDL_Quit();
                    break;
                case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                    //this is the line that is not working as expected.
                    std::cout << &event.key.keysym.sym << std::endl;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` in `std::cout << &event.key.keysym.sym << std::endl;` is unnecessary. That is the cause of printing address instead of actual data.

However even with `&` removed this will not output you 'f' for `f` keypressed, since value is integer enumeration, and not ASCII code values.

Answer (score 5):

Use SDL_GetKeyName() to get a printable string that represents the key pressed.  Since SDL_Keycode (SDLKey in SDL1.2) is implemented as an enumeration, it cannot be simply converted to a printable character, particularly for keys like "shift" and "alt".

Try this:

```
std::cout << SDL_GetKeyName(event.key.keysym.sym) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

The keycode for f is SDLK_f

A simple if statement should do it:

```
case SDL_KEYDOWN:
    if( event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_f )
        std::cout << "f was pressed" << std::endl;
    break ;   //this was missing
```

SDL doesn't distinguish cases so you need an extra check for that, if was shift pressed etc.

Comment: Worked, thanks. I can't accept your answer for 6 minutes though! :'(